# How to write the function to lit LED on sense HAT simulator

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, node-red

I am trying to light a LED on senseHAT simulator. In the documentation it says we have to provide the coordinates and the color in the **,,** format. But it doesn't mention how we need to set the **msg.payload** value inorder to actually lit the simulators LED. I have been searching for a while and I couldn't find any examples using nodeRED. All the examples available are done using python API.

The [documentation of the nodeRED senseHAT simulator](http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-pi-sense-hat) provides only the value formats.

Comment: The documentation describes it very well. With multiple examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
msg.payload="0,0,#001100";
```

where `x=0` and `y=0`  are the coordinates of the 8x8 LED Matrix, which values from 0-7
You can append multiple commands in single msg.payload using `\n`

For example:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload+"\n0,1,#1100000";
```